# Cant run dotCMS

Tags: java, eclipse, dotcms

I am new at dotCMS and I can not run dotcms, here is my log file. Help me please me with this problem.

> java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'TxDataSource.DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler'
>                   at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.shutdown(DBConnectionManager.java:136) ~[dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.shutdown(JobStoreSupport.java:680) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.shutdown(JobStoreCMT.java:149) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.shutdown(QuartzScheduler.java:696) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1349) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1509) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at com.dotmarketing.quartz.DotSchedulerFactory.(DotSchedulerFactory.java:39) [bin/:?]
>                   at com.dotmarketing.quartz.DotSchedulerFactory.getInstance(DotSchedulerFactory.java:104) [bin/:?]
>                   at com.dotmarketing.quartz.QuartzUtils.stopSchedulers(QuartzUtils.java:382) [bin/:?]
>                   at com.dotmarketing.listeners.ContextLifecycleListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLifecycleListener.java:33) [bin/:?]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4767) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5371) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>               [05/10/16 14:43:32:228 ALMT]  WARN quartz.DotJobStore: Database connection shutdown unsuccessful.
>               java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'null'
>                   at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.shutdown(DBConnectionManager.java:136) ~[dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.shutdown(JobStoreCMT.java:152) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.shutdown(QuartzScheduler.java:696) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1349) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1509) [dot.quartz-all-1.8.6_2.jar:?]
>                   at com.dotmarketing.quartz.DotSchedulerFactory.(DotSchedulerFactory.java:39) [bin/:?]
>                   at com.dotmarketing.quartz.DotSchedulerFactory.getInstance(DotSchedulerFactory.java:104) [bin/:?]
>                   at com.dotmarketing.quartz.QuartzUtils.stopSchedulers(QuartzUtils.java:382) [bin/:?]
>                   at com.dotmarketing.listeners.ContextLifecycleListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLifecycleListener.java:33) [bin/:?]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4767) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5371) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
>               [05/10/16 14:43:32:229 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
>               [05/10/16 14:43:32:229 ALMT] ERROR listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: A error ocurred trying to shutdown the Schedulers.
>               [05/10/16 14:43:32:234 ALMT]  WARN reindex.ReindexThread: ReindexThread not running (or already shutting down)
>               [05/10/16 14:43:34:246 ALMT] ERROR db.DbConnectionFactory: ---------- DBConnectionFactory: error : java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

```
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
        [05/10/16 14:43:34:247 ALMT] ERROR lang.System: Error setting up local server id 
        [05/10/16 14:43:34:266 ALMT] ERROR listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: A error ocurred trying to shutdown the ClusterThread.
        [05/10/16 14:43:34:266 ALMT] ERROR listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: A error ocurred trying to shutdown the Cache subsystem.
        [05/10/16 14:43:34:266 ALMT]  INFO listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: Finished shuting down.
        [05/10/16 14:43:34:274 ALMT] ERROR cluster.ClusterFactory: can't remove from cluster
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dotcms.enterprise.cluster.ClusterFactory.removeNodeFromCluster(SourceFile:284) ~[ee-3.6.0.jar:?]
            at com.dotcms.enterprise.license.LicenseManager$1.run(SourceFile:200) [eelic-3.6.0.jar:?]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:976 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:979 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:979 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:979 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                            7777777   7777       7777     77777777  
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:979 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                 OO       777777777  77777      77777    77777777   
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:979 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                OOO      77777       777777     77777   7777        
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:      OOOOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOOO 7777         7777777   777777   7777        
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:     OOOO  OOOOO  OOOO  OOOO    OOOO    7777         7777777  7777777    777777     
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO  OOO    OOOO   OOOO    7777         77777777 777 7777     777777   
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO OOOO    OOOO   OOOO    7777         777  777 777 7777        7777  
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO  OOO    OOOO   OOOO    77777        777  777777  7777         7777 
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:     OOOO   OOOO  OOOO   OOO    OOOO     77777       777   7777   7777        7777  
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:      OOOOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOO      OOOOO    777777777  777   7777   7777  777777777   
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                          Content Management System 
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:980 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 14:49:40:981 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 14:49:42:075 ALMT]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: Initializing in-memory repository...
        [05/10/16 14:49:42:168 ALMT]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: ...initialized in-memory repository.
        [05/10/16 14:49:42:168 ALMT]  INFO impl.CmisRepositoryContextListener: Initialized Services Factory: com.dotcms.enterprise.cmis.server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:207 ALMT]  INFO business.CacheLocator: loading cache administrator: com.dotmarketing.business.ChainableCacheAdministratorImpl
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:272 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : default: 1000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:272 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : livecache: 1000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:272 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : workingcache: 1000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:272 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : adminconfigpool: 100
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:272 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : companypool: 10
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:272 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : contentletcache: 5000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:273 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : csscache: 2500
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:273 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : fileassetmetadatacache: 200
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:273 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : identifiercache: 50000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:273 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : indiciescache: 8
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:273 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : logmappercache: 10
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : navcache: 1000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : parentpermissionablecache: 10000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : permissioncache: 50000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : portletpool: 100
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : publishingendpointcache: 100
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : pushedassetscache: 5000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : structurecache: 500
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : templatecache: 500
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:274 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : translatedquerycache: 5000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:275 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : velocityuservtlcache: 500
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:275 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : versioncache: 50000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:275 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : versioninfocache: 50000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:275 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : workflowactioncache: 10000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:275 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Cache Config Memory : workflowtaskcache: 10000
        [05/10/16 14:49:44:875 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Building Cache : structurecache, size:500,Concurrency:32
        [05/10/16 14:49:45:014 ALMT]  INFO util.SystemProperties: Loading file:/C:/dotcms_3.6/bin/system.properties
        [05/10/16 14:49:45:016 ALMT]  INFO util.SystemProperties: Loading file:/C:/dotcms_3.6/bin/system-ext.properties
        [05/10/16 14:49:45:128 ALMT]  INFO util.PropsLoader: Loading file:/C:/dotcms_3.6/bin/portal.properties
        [05/10/16 14:49:45:129 ALMT]  INFO util.PropsLoader: Loading file:/C:/dotcms_3.6/bin/portal-ext.properties
        [05/10/16 14:49:45:138 ALMT]  INFO filters.CharsetEncodingFilter: Destroying character encoding filter...
        [05/10/16 14:49:45:142 ALMT]  INFO listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: Shutdown event received, executing a clean shutdown.
        [05/10/16 14:49:45:526 ALMT]  WARN reindex.ReindexThread: ReindexThread not running (or already shutting down)                                                                                
        [05/10/16 15:03:55:183 ALMT]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: Initializing in-memory repository...
        [05/10/16 15:03:55:234 ALMT]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: ...initialized in-memory repository.
        [05/10/16 15:03:55:234 ALMT]  INFO impl.CmisRepositoryContextListener: Initialized Services Factory: 
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:239 ALMT]  INFO simpl.SimpleThreadPool: Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: localhost-startStop-1
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:259 ALMT]  INFO core.SchedulerSignalerImpl: Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:259 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Quartz Scheduler v.1.8.6 created.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:260 ALMT]  INFO simpl.RAMJobStore: RAMJobStore initialized.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:260 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v1.8.6) 'DotMarketingQuartzLocalScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
          Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
          NOT STARTED.
          Currently in standby mode.
          Number of jobs executed: 0
          Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 50 threads.
          Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:260 ALMT]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler 'DotMarketingQuartzLocalScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:260 ALMT]  INFO impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.6
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:260 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:260 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:281 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:281 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:281 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:294 ALMT]  INFO core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DotMarketingQuartzExclusiveScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:301 ALMT]  WARN reindex.ReindexThread: ReindexThread not running (or already shutting down)
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:361 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ===== Calling shutdown [Guava Memory Cache].
        [05/10/16 15:03:58:361 ALMT]  INFO listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: Finished shuting down. 
        [05/10/16 15:48:04:297 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 15:48:04:297 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                          Content Management System 
        [05/10/16 15:48:04:298 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 15:48:04:298 ALMT]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
        [05/10/16 15:48:05:473 ALMT]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: Initializing in-memory repository...
        [05/10/16 15:48:05:528 ALMT]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: ...initialized in-memory repository.
        [05/10/16 15:48:05:528 ALMT]  INFO impl.CmisRepositoryContextListener: Initialized Services Factory: com.dotcms.enterprise.cmis.server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl
        [05/10/16 15:48:15:837 ALMT]  INFO cfg.Configuration: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
        [05/10/16 15:48:15:838 ALMT]  WARN cfg.Configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
        [05/10/16 15:48:15:842 ALMT]  INFO cfg.Configuration: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
        [05/10/16 15:48:15:842 ALMT]  INFO cfg.Configuration: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
        [05/10/16 15:48:15:842 ALMT]  WARN cfg.Configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
        [05/10/16 15:48:16:279 ALMT]  INFO cfg.Binder: Mapping class: com.dotcms.repackage.com.liferay.counter.ejb.CounterHBM -> Counter
        [05/10/16 15:48:16:386 ALMT] ERROR util.HibernateConfiguration: null
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.liferay.portal.util.HibernateConfiguration.init(HibernateConfiguration.java:75) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.liferay.util.dao.hibernate.SessionConfiguration.<init>(SessionConfiguration.java:44) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.liferay.portal.util.HibernateConfiguration.<init>(HibernateConfiguration.java:44) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at com.liferay.util.InstancePool._get(InstancePool.java:69) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.liferay.util.InstancePool.get(InstancePool.java:39) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.liferay.portal.util.HibernateUtil._getSessionConfigurationInstance(HibernateUtil.java:86) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.liferay.portal.util.HibernateUtil.openSession(HibernateUtil.java:68) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.liferay.portal.ejb.BasePersistence.openSession(BasePersistence.java:43) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.liferay.portal.ejb.CompanyPersistence.findByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistence.java:165) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.liferay.portal.ejb.CompanyUtil.findByPrimaryKey(CompanyUtil.java:128) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.dotmarketing.cms.factories.PublicCompanyFactory.getDefaultCompany(PublicCompanyFactory.java:55) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.dotmarketing.servlets.InitServlet.init(InitServlet.java:99) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4901) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5188) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
        [05/10/16 15:48:16:866 ALMT]  INFO guava.GuavaCache: ***     Building Cache : languagecacheimpl, size:1000,Concurrency:32
        [05/10/16 15:48:16:905 ALMT]  INFO cfg.Configuration: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
        [05/10/16 15:48:16:905 ALMT]  INFO cfg.Configuration: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
        [05/10/16 15:48:16:906 ALMT]  WARN cfg.Configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
        [05/10/16 15:48:16:907 ALMT] ERROR business.LanguageFactoryImpl: getLanguage failed:com.dotmarketing.exception.DotHibernateException: Error setting Query
        com.dotmarketing.exception.DotHibernateException: Error setting Query
            at com.dotmarketing.db.HibernateUtil.setQuery(HibernateUtil.java:199) ~[dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.dotmarketing.portlets.languagesmanager.business.LanguageFactoryImpl.getLanguage(LanguageFactoryImpl.java:70) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.dotmarketing.portlets.languagesmanager.business.LanguageFactoryImpl.getDefaultLanguage(LanguageFactoryImpl.java:234) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.dotmarketing.portlets.languagesmanager.business.LanguageAPIImpl.getDefaultLanguage(LanguageAPIImpl.java:92) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.dotmarketing.servlets.BinaryExporterServlet.<init>(BinaryExporterServlet.java:97) [dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:121) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4901) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5188) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
        Caused by: com.dotmarketing.exception.DotHibernateException: Unable to get Hibernate Session 
            at com.dotmarketing.db.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java:676) ~[dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            at com.dotmarketing.db.HibernateUtil.setQuery(HibernateUtil.java:195) ~[dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
            ... 25 more
        Caused by: com.dotmarketing.exception.DotHibernateException: Unable to build Session Factory 
        [05/10/16 15:48:46:652 ALMT]  INFO cfg.Configuration: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
        [05/10/16 15:48:46:652 ALMT]  INFO cfg.Configuration: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
        [05/10/16 15:48:46:653 ALMT]  WARN cfg.Configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
        [05/10/16 15:48:46:908 ALMT] ERROR portal._500_jsp: cms500Page cant display Error setting Query
```

I'm sorry if this is duplicate question, I searched and looked them but they are didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like dotCMS cannot connect to your DB:

```
 Caused by: com.dotmarketing.exception.DotHibernateException: Unable to get Hibernate Session 
        at com.dotmarketing.db.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java:676) ~[dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
        at com.dotmarketing.db.HibernateUtil.setQuery(HibernateUtil.java:195) ~[dotcms_3.6.0_3876030.jar:?]
        ... 25 more
```

Make sure your db connection pool is set up correctly in tomcat's context.xml  and the user / password can connect to the db.